# C# - Using async for a high-end server

Tags: c#, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm not sure if using async for what I'm planning to do is the most efficient way, so I decided to ask you guys what you think about it.

**Backstory**: I'm developing a server emulation software for a MMORPG game which has NPCs laying around in it's world. You (the client) can interact with the NPCs through dialogs. Dialogs show text to the player as well as choices (Some dialogs are Yes/No dialogs, Accept/Decline, etcetera).

I've decided to use C# as a scripting interface for the NPCs' scripts. When the server initiates, it compiles and saves the assembly of the compiled scripts for each NPC and when a player converse with one of them it executes the desired script.

Now, let's say the user has to give input to the server. First, we display a window with a Yes/No question.

The client shows the following:

"Would you like to receive an Apple?"
Yes/No

The script itself halts after it sent the dialog until it receives a response from the client using async. The method that sends the dialog returns a Task of boolean (true for yes, false for no) and is async. The response is a type of TaskCompletionSource of boolean. So, the method is like so:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> _response; 

public async Task<bool> SendDialog()
{
     _response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
     [... the packet that shows the dialog]
     return await _response.Task;
}
```

So, as you can see, it awaits until the response has been set and only then returns it.

Once the server has received the packet of the response, it sets the response based on the input.

```
_response.SetResult(...);
```

And then the script continues (as the input has been given).

Now, I wanted to ask you guys how efficient it is for a high-end server and can it be improved somehow? Or is there another way to halt a script until an input is given?

Comment: This is a good idea. Normally, this is being done by writing the code in a state-machine style. The C# compiler does that for you when you use await or yield.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is well weighted and efficient because it has been specifically designed for these kinds of high-level tasks: GUI interactions, high-level business logic, parallel tasks, task chains, etc.

It is not as efficient though when used in low-level applications like I/O operations with small memory footprint, syscalls, high-grained tasks, etc.

By the way, looking at your example, I can see an unnecessary await there. You can simplify instead:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> _response; 

public Task<bool> SendDialog()
{
     _response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
     // [... the packet that shows the dialog]
     return _response.Task;
}
```

By definition, `async` methods are just compiler generated tasks. Since you use `TaskCompletionSource` here, you're already generating a task manually. There's no need to wrap it around another (compiler generated) task.

Comment: But without the await keyword the script won't halt, am I correct?

Comment: It will because the code that calls `SendDialog` will await for the task it returns. In your code, some party which calls the `SendDialog()` method should use the `await` statement because the method returns `Task<bool>` not `bool`. My correction does not change that behaviour - the code still returns a task, thus could be awaited.

Comment: What I mean is that somewhere in your calling code you write: `bool result = await SendDialog()`. It doesn't go anywhere.